# AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing' has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, keras

When I am trying to import the `Tokenizer()` function in Keras, I am getting the following error.

I am following official Keras documentation at https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#tokenizer

```
import keras
tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
```

Getting error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing' has no attribute 'text'
```

Using Keras version '2.1.3'

Where I have done wrong?

Comment: Don't you have to create a new preprocessing object and then invoke its `Tokenizer()` function ?

Comment: @Mawg nope, `Tokenizer` is a class in the `keras.preprocessing.text` module

Comment: See this page http://www.orbifold.net/default/2017/01/10/embedding-and-tokenizer-in-keras/

Comment: The thing is that, I am not getting text attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
from keras.preprocessing import text
tokenizer = text.Tokenizer(...)
```

The reason is that `keras/preprocessing/__init__.py` doesn't import nor expose the `text` submodule

Comment: Yes. I am new in python. But need to know one thing. Why keras.preprocessing.text is not found ?

Comment: I already explained it - "The reason is that keras/preprocessing/__init__.py doesn't import nor expose the text submodule".